# Manipulating sympy polynomial

Tags: python, sympy, polynomials

I have a polynomial with multiple variables, for example:

```
2c1^2*c2*x^3+c2*x
```

represented in python by

```
Poly(2*c1**2*c2*x**3 + c2*x, c1, c2, x, domain='ZZ')
```

I would like to iterate over the monomials, and each time I find "c1^2", divide this monomial by c1*x. For the example above, the result should be:

```
2c1*c2*x^2+c2*x
```

represented in python by

```
Poly(2*c1*c2*x**2 + c2*x, c1, c2, x, domain='ZZ')
```

how can this be done? Specifically, how do I manipulate each monomial separately? I expect to have polynomials with dozens of monomials.
Is sympy.Poly the appropriate package to use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you how I would do it.

```
from sympy import *
c1, c2, x = symbols("c1, c2, x")
poly = Poly(2*c1**2*c2*x**3 + c2*x, c1, c2, x, domain='ZZ')

# convert the Poly to an expression
expr = poly.as_expr()
# expr is of type Add (an addition). Let's extract the addends
monomials = expr.args
# perform the manipulation
mod_expr = Add(*[m / (c1 * x) if m.has(c1**2) else m for m in monomials])
# create a new Poly: use the new expression and the original symbols/domain
new_poly = Poly(mod_expr, poly.args[1:], domain=poly.domain)
print(new_poly)
# out: Poly(2*c1*c2*x**2 + c2*x, c1, c2, x, domain='ZZ')
```

Regarding your question:

> Is sympy.Poly the appropriate package to use in this case?

That's up to you to decide. As you have seen from this simple example, I operated directly on a symbolic expression. So, if you input your polynomials as symbolic expressions instead of `Poly`, you might save yourself some typing.

Comment: Thanks! 
I am not fluent in python so I will use this opportunity to also learn about the asterisk operator you used in the Add expression. Does it mean you unpack the list into a list of parameters?

Comment: Thanks! 
I am not fluent in python so I will use this opportunity to also learn about the asterisk operator you used in the Add expression. Does it mean you unpack the list into a list of parameters?

Comment: Precisely. `Add` requires zero or more addends. For example `Add(a1, a2)` will results into `a1+a2`. But you can use list comprehension to create a list of addends and then use the star operator to unpack the elements. For example, `l = [a1, a2]` and then `Add(*l)`, which is equivalent to type `Add(a1, a2)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to target `c1**2` and not powers of it (like `c1**4 = c1**2*c1**2`) and not extractable values of it (like `c1**3 = c1**2*c1`) then `xreplace` should work:

```py
>>> from sympy import symbols
>>> c1,c2 = symbols('c1 c2')
>>> (c1**2 + c1**2 + c1 + c2).xreplace({c1**2: c1/x})  # c1**2/(c1*x) = c1/x
c1**3 + c1 + c1/x + c2
```